# open http connection for audio streaming 

Tags: android, http, audio-streaming

I am trying to create an application to play a live radio.I am using the following method to open the http connection,and giving this url "http://64.62.xxx.xxxx:xxx/"
But i am getting nullpointer exception,

```
                public InputStream OpenHttpConnection(String urlString) throws IOException
{
    InputStream in = null;
    int response = -1;

    URL url = new URL(urlString); 
    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();


    if (!(conn instanceof HttpURLConnection))                     
        throw new IOException("Error connecting");

    try{
        HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
        httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
        httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        httpConn.connect(); 
        response = httpConn.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("Response : "+response);
        if (response == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) 
        {
            in = httpConn.getInputStream();
        }     
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new IOException("Error connecting");            
    }
    return in;     
}
```

Is there any other way for streaming data from such kind of url or i need to add something else in the above method ??

I created an instance of the  MediaPlayer.My logcat is displaying the following error :

05-25 15:50:08.067: DEBUG/MediaPlayer(1032): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
05-25 15:50:08.189: WARN/MediaPlayer(1032): info/warning (1, 26)
05-25 15:50:08.217: ERROR/PlayerDriver(31): Command PLAYER_INIT completed with an error or info PVMFFailure
05-25 15:50:08.217: ERROR/MediaPlayer(1032): error (1, -1)
05-25 15:50:08.237: WARN/PlayerDriver(31): PVMFInfoErrorHandlingComplete
05-25 15:50:08.357: DEBUG/MediaPlayer(1032): create failed:
05-25 15:50:08.357: DEBUG/MediaPlayer(1032): java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1
05-25 15:50:08.357: DEBUG/MediaPlayer(1032):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(Native Method)
05-25 15:50:08.357: DEBUG/MediaPlayer(1032):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.create(MediaPlayer.java:608)
05-25 15:50:08.357: DEBUG/MediaPlayer(1032):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.create(MediaPlayer.java:585)
05-25 15:50:08.357: DEBUG/MediaPlayer(1032):     at org.sample.AudioPlayer.AudioPlayer.PlayRadio(AudioPlayer.java:190)
05-25 15:50:08.357: DEBUG/MediaPlayer(1032):     at org.sample.AudioPlayer.AudioPlayer.access$1(AudioPlayer.java:123)
05-25 15:50:08.357: DEBUG/MediaPlayer(1032):     at org.sample.AudioPlayer.AudioPlayer$3.onClick(AudioPlayer.java:77)
05-25 15:50:08.357: DEBUG/MediaPlayer(1032):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2364)
05-25 15:50:08.357: DEBUG/MediaPlayer(1032):     at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:4179)
05-25 15:50:08.357: DEBUG/MediaPlayer(1032):     at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:6541)
05-25 15:50:08.357: DEBUG/MediaPlayer(1032):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3709)
05-25 15:50:08.357: DEBUG/MediaPlayer(1032):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
05-25 15:50:08.357: DEBUG/MediaPlayer(1032):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
05-25 15:50:08.357: DEBUG/MediaPlayer(1032):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
05-25 15:50:08.357: DEBUG/MediaPlayer(1032):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
05-25 15:50:08.357: DEBUG/MediaPlayer(1032):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1659)
05-25 15:50:08.357: DEBUG/MediaPlayer(1032):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1107)
05-25 15:50:08.357: DEBUG/MediaPlayer(1032):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2061)
05-25 15:50:08.357: DEBUG/MediaPlayer(1032):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1643)
05-25 15:50:08.357: DEBUG/MediaPlayer(1032):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1691)
05-25 15:50:08.357: DEBUG/MediaPlayer(1032):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-25 15:50:08.357: DEBUG/MediaPlayer(1032):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-25 15:50:08.357: DEBUG/MediaPlayer(1032):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
05-25 15:50:08.357: DEBUG/MediaPlayer(1032):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-25 15:50:08.357: DEBUG/MediaPlayer(1032):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-25 15:50:08.357: DEBUG/MediaPlayer(1032):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
05-25 15:50:08.357: DEBUG/MediaPlayer(1032):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
05-25 15:50:08.357: DEBUG/MediaPlayer(1032):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-25 15:51:05.277: DEBUG/dalvikvm(97): GC freed 14 objects / 560 bytes in 127ms
05-25 15:51:13.280: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(1032): Shutting down VM
05-25 15:51:13.280: WARN/dalvikvm(1032): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
05-25 15:51:13.280: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1032): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

First of  check the connection from the server u could use a HTTP Debugger 
As u want to play audio
Create a mediaplayer instanse and set the filedescriptor in SetDataSource

```
m_player.setOnPreparedListener(this);
m_player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
m_player.setDataSource(filedescriptor fd);
m_player.prepareAsync();
```

Comment: thanks for the reply jegan_u,i have already created an instance of media player..i am getting this error:05-25 15:50:08.067: DEBUG/MediaPlayer(1032): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
05-25 15:50:08.217: ERROR/PlayerDriver(31): Command PLAYER_INIT completed with an error or info PVMFFailure
05-25 15:50:08.217: ERROR/MediaPlayer(1032): error (1, -1)
05-25 15:50:08.237: WARN/PlayerDriver(31): PVMFInfoErrorHandlingComplete
05-25 15:50:08.357: DEBUG/MediaPlayer(1032): create failed:
05-25 15:50:08.357: DEBUG/MediaPlayer(1032): java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1